# What is the appropriate motion sensor for movement?

Tags: raspberry-pi, sensors, motion

I want to find a wireless motion sensor for movement which should be sensitive for the up, down, left and right movement. I have found some like IMU sensor. Could you please guys tell me if you know a better one which should be wireless sensor and easy to play with the raspberry pi 3 ?